# list aggregation

Tags: sql, ansi-sql

Is there a way to do list aggregation in ANSI SQL? I am aware that some of the RDBMS provide in-built functions like listagg() in Oracle etc. I tried to look for the ANSI standard document but looks like we have to purchase it (would have been nice if this was available for free as a reference). Thanks.

Comment: What database are you using that is 100% ANSI-compatible?  Also, the function in MS SQL is *not* `STUFF()`.  The *functionality* is XML processing.  `STUFF()` is just used to remove the separator from the beginning of the string.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Describe the problem, and add sample table data and the expected result (both as well formatted text.)

Comment: Why question is down marked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, **NO**, those are RDBMS specific implementation as you have already noted down (or) `GROUP_CONCAT()` in case of MySQL. Moreover, ANSI SQL is a standard and not a product by itself.

Comment: What I meant was accomplishing concatenate function that complies with ANSI SQL